# No value accessor for form control with name:

Tags: angular, forms, form-control, formgroups

I continue to get this error regardless of what I try.

html:

```
<form  id="newCommittee" [formGroup]="newCommittee" >
        <Input placeholder="Committee Name" class="col-4" formControlName="newCommitteeName"  >
</form>
```

ts:

```
import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) { 
    this.newCommittee = this.fb.group({
      newCommitteeName: new FormControl
    });
  }
```

Results in the error:

No value accessor for form control with name: 'newCommitteeDescription' at _throwError (forms.js:2144)
at setUpControl (forms.js:2054)

Comment: Isn't it missing () on new FormControl?

Should be new FormControl()

Answer (score 1):

your'e mixing constructor of FormGroup/FormControl and FormBuilder, choose one of them

```
this.newCommittee=new FormGroup({
   newCommitteName:new FormControl('value')
})
```

//or

```
this.newCommitte=this.fb.group({
  newCommitteName:['value']
})
```

See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-importing-the-formbuilder-class)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `()` after `new FormControl()`.

It should be:

```
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder ) { 
    this.newCommittee = this.fb.group({
      newCommitteeName: new FormControl() // HERE
    });
  }
```